# What is mean by Differential Daisy Chain UART?

Tags: uart, communication

What is mean by differential daisy chain UART? And what is the difference between UART and differential daisy chain UART?

While reading datasheet I come across this concept if anybody knows then I would like to know it.

Comment: link to the datasheet

Comment: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq76pl455a-q1.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It most likely means that the output (TX) of one UART is fed to the input (RX) on another one. The benefit is that from the host/microcontroller side you need just one UART to communicate with many slave devices in a chain. This is similar to a daisy chain SPI (for example: like chain of shift registers).

This of course has to be supported by the protocol, so for example when you send message to the third device in the chain the other devices must be somehow bypassed.

In this particular case the functionality is explained in "7.3.10 Stacked Daisy-Chain Communications" of the datasheet. Basically your MCU talks via a standard UART to a "master" chip that is connected with differential lines to the other chips in the chain and uses a proprietary protocol.

Comment: that was my guess too, then I read the data sheet,

Answer (score 0):

differential is where two wires carry the signal in opposite sense - one goes high when the other goes low and vice versa.

daisy-chain is several devices connect in a directed chain-like structure each connected to it neighbours, see figure 17 on page 32.

But the comm connectors seem to use a biphase code, not NRZ like a normal UART
(page 33) and the document does not seem to call these connectors a UART anywhere

RX and TX OTOH are for connection to an ordinary UART.